# Beego uses func Request.ParseMultipartForm function on input.go; however Go does not recommend it

Tags: go, beego

Because of `ParseFormOrMulitForm` function in Beego, I got an ERROR:

> Handler crashed with error http: multipart handled by ParseMultipartForm

Beego uses `Request.ParseMultipartForm` function in [input.go](https://github.com/astaxie/beego/blob/master/context/input.go#L390).

```
// ParseFormOrMulitForm parseForm or parseMultiForm based on Content-type
func (input *BeegoInput) ParseFormOrMulitForm(maxMemory int64) error {
    // Parse the body depending on the content type.
    if strings.Contains(input.Header("Content-Type"), "multipart/form-data") {
        if err := input.Context.Request.ParseMultipartForm(maxMemory); err != nil {
            return errors.New("Error parsing request body:" + err.Error())
        }
    } else if err := input.Context.Request.ParseForm(); err != nil {
        return errors.New("Error parsing request body:" + err.Error())
    }
    return nil
}
```

However, I found that Go does not recommend to use `Request.ParseMultipartForm` for stream processing.

https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go:

> Use MultipartReader function instead of ParseMultipartForm to process the request body as a stream.

```
362 // MultipartReader returns a MIME multipart reader if this is a
363 // multipart/form-data POST request, else returns nil and an error.
364 // Use this function instead of ParseMultipartForm to
365 // process the request body as a stream.
366 func (r *Request) MultipartReader() (*multipart.Reader, error) {
367     if r.MultipartForm == multipartByReader {
368         return nil, errors.New("http: MultipartReader called twice")
369     }
370     if r.MultipartForm != nil {
371         return nil, errors.New("http: multipart handled by ParseMultipartForm")
372     }
373     r.MultipartForm = multipartByReader
374     return r.multipartReader()
375 }
376
```

How to fix it?

Comment: At least for now it looks like a bug. I think you should discuss it with Beego maintainers.

Comment: Are you certain that you need to process the request as a stream? Can you just use the `Context.Request` directly instead of the convenience methods on BeegoInput?

Comment: I need it because "jQuery-file-upload" requires it.